# Unable to generate refresh Access token

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am able to generate an access token but the response object return null for refresh token following is my code.

JavaScript:

```
 function connect_dfa(oauthurl,scop,redirect,clientId) {


            var width = 1024;
            var height = 512;
            var left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2);
            var top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
            var specs = 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,copyhistory=no,width='+width+',height='+height+',top='+top+',left='+left;
            var url = oauthurl+"&scope="+scop+"&redirect_uri="+redirect+"&response_type=code&client_id="+clientId;
            alert (url);
            var win = window.open(url, 'scgid platform', specs, false);
        return false;
    }
```

once it redirect to redirect URL following code generate access token using the authentication code:

```
flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, SCOPES).build();


final TokenResponse response = flow.newTokenRequest(dfaToken).setRedirectUri(CALLBACK_URI)
        .execute();

System.out.println(response.getAccessToken());
System.out.println(response.getRefreshToken());
```

It return me an access token such as : `ya29.CgH2ZBKtHUBr6uJtOs8q0q2vf_tllv_UYMF-Vcd-bODGOgoxqz05mzfDkymEGjVdmYuw2Os4FFpQPQ"`
but reuturn NULL for Refresh Token.

What m doing wrong since I am able to generate access token.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the refresh token with Google OAuth2 Javascript library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015451/how-to-get-the-refresh-token-with-google-oauth2-javascript-library)

Comment: No this is a different issue and not a duplicate question could you please remove above comments.

Comment: The refresh token is only returned on the initial authorization. Try withdrawing permission and trying again

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `"&access_type=offline"` to the authorization window url in order to get refresh token. For details: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to generate refresh token :**

Step 1 :
Configure return url of your App to http://0.0.0.0. So that it will redirect you to localhost with code.
Example : `http://0.0.0.0/?state=authenticated&code=<code>`

Step 2: Navigate to below url with your client code

```
https://account.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>&state=authenticated
```

Step 3:
Grant access to box api then copy `<code>` from your url.
Example : `http://0.0.0.0/?state=authenticated&code=<code>`

Step 4: Do post request to https://api.box.com/oauth2/token with below parameters

```
grant_type = authorization_code,
    client_id = <client_id>,
    client_secret = <client_secret>,
    code = code you generated in step 3
```

This will return you below object:

```
access_token,
expires_in, 
restricted_to, 
refresh_token, 
token_type, 
created_time
```

Refresh token expiry : 60 days.

Access Token expiry : 60 mins.

Note : Use code with in 10 sec

Note : Every time you regenerate your access_token token you will get new refresh token.
[For more information refer box documentations](https://developer.box.com/v2.0/reference#authorize)