# How to refresh access_token from Google OAuth 2.0 API in a pure client-side application?

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

My question is already answered to about 90% in the following question:
[How to get the refresh token with Google OAuth2 Javascript library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015451/how-to-get-the-refresh-token-with-google-oauth2-javascript-library)

I have a client-side JS web app. In this application I want to use Google APIs. To do that I need to refresh the `access_token` every hour, but **without** showing the Google login screen to the user again and again. Currently there's no server-side code and I want to avoid server-side code so my application is more portable (e.g. Electron).

That means that the only possibility I have is option two from the answer in the question linked above. It says:

> Have your client simply keep requesting access tokens as it needs them. Set `immediate=true` so there is no visible interaction with the user.

I've looked through both documentations: [Google API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js) and [Google Identity Platform](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2) (which is the direct OAuth 2.0 endpoint that's being used by the Client Library in the background).

I can't find an option called `immediate`. But this anser tells me that it should be possible to refresh an `access_token` within a pure client-side web app but without using a `refresh_token`. But how?

Also, I totally want to avoid using the client library because it's too difficult to integrate it with a webpack based project... So I'm primarly interested in what the HTTP request agains the OAuth endpoint should look like.

*edit: fixed wrong link*

Answer (score 0):

The answer you linked to was referring to an earlier version of the client library. The current version is documented at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent and I believe (NB not tested) that the equivalent to `immediate=true` is `prompt=none`

Comment: It seems possible that this is what I'm looking for. What else cought my eye though is the `.grantOfflineAccess()` method. Now I need to find out what's the difference and, once I know exactly which one I need, what that does from a HTTP perspective so I can implement it myself. Thanks so far.

Comment: grantOfflineAccess is intended to be used in conjunction with a server auth flow. If you're looking for a pure JS/browser solution, grantOfflineAccess isn't it. I saw a comment on https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/232 that " however, as GSI v2 takes care of caching and refreshing token", so it may well be the library does the job for you.

Comment: I've opened an issue myself now: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/343 There I was basically told the same thing. It's just: The automatic refresh of the token doesn't seem to work. More details are listed in the issue.